# How do I use STL std::list with objects?

Tags: key-value, stdlist, lower-bound

I want to create linked lists of objects sorted by an object attribute (physical size);  but so far it seems I will have to code them myself...
These lists will be short, typically a dozen nodes each;  but I may have up to a thousand lists; so I can't afford the extra weight of using std::map's.  In fact, I'd be quite happy with single linked list.
But I need the node to be more than just a value.
The key value in my objects is rarely going to change;  however elements will have to come out of one list and move to another quite often.
((Actual use: One list per quad, in a quad-tree (as for collision detection, etc);  objects sorted by size, as the larger objects are less numerous but need to be picked quickly from larger ranges, so they should come up first in the lists.))

But every example I find for using std::list to maintain sorted lists uses a list of integers as the example;  but that's not very useful;  what I have is objects that have one value member to be sorted by.
I was thinking of using lower_bound to find the insertion point, then insert the object;  but the lower_bound iterator takes a begin, and end, and a plain value as the third argument;  I see no mechanism by which I can specify to use a particular member of my objects to sort by.
I could, of course, define a conversion operator,
`my_object_type::int(){ return sortby; }`
Would that work?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found my answer in this reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lower_bound-in-cpp/
under "Syntax 2";  there is provision for a fourth
argument being a comparison functor.  So, something
like this should work (not tested yet):

```
class pnt_proxy
{
    int x; //position
    int y;
    point* real_pnt; //the real point this represents
public:
    float sz; //rough largest diagonal across object
}


class pproxy_cmp : public std::binary_function< pnt_proxy, pnt_proxy, bool >
{
public:
    bool operator()( pnt_proxy const & a, pnt_proxy const & b ) const
    {
        return a.sz < b.sz;
    }
};

std::list< pnt_proxy > ll;

void insert_sorted( pnt_proxy const & pp )
{
    if( ll.size() )
    {
        std::list<pnt_proxy>::iterator insert_at;
        insert_at =
          std::lower_bound( ll.begin(), ll.end(), pp, pproxy_cmp() );
        ll.insert( insert_at, pp );
    }
    else ll.push_back( pp );
}
```